# Help in a DP problem

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic, intervals

I'm trying to solve a problem from SPOJ ( [link](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/MHLAR10/) ), which can be briefly described like this: Given n intervals, each with an integer beginning and end, and given the end with max time ( let's call it max_end ) , find in how many ways you can choose a set of intervals that covers 1...max_end. Intervals may overlap. I tried a DP; first sort by end time, then dp[ i ] is a pair, where dp[ i ].first is the minimum number of intervals needed to cover 1...end[ i ] **last using interval i** and dp[ i ].second is the number of ways to do it. Here's my main DP loop:

```
for( int i = 1; i < n; i ++ ) {
    for( int j = 0; j < i; j ++ ) {
        if( ! ( x[ j ].end >= x[ i ].start - 1 ) )
            continue;
        if( dp[ j ].first + 1 < dp[ i ].first ) {
            dp[ i ].first = dp[ j ].first + 1;
            dp[ i ].second = dp[ j ].second;
        }
        else if( dp[ j ].first + 1 == dp[ i ].first ) {
            dp[ i ].second += dp[ j ].second;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Can somebody please tell me where I have a mistake? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What are your initial values for dp[0]?  Also, the linked question specifically asks for the number of **minimal** set of intervals that cover a particular day; are you sure that this algorithm guarantees that?

Comment: Hi, I initialize dp[0].first = dp[0].second = 1 if start[ 0 ] = 1. And I think my algorithm does guarantee that. If you have any solution in your mind I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your intuition here?  I can't follow why your code works.

Comment: I don't see how this O(N^2) algorithm is going to solve the oviously O(2^N) problem

Comment: Suppose you want to calculate dp[i] supposing you calculated all dp[1..i - 1]. For each j in 1..i - 1: if you can cover till the end of interval j, and the interval i would complement the rest of end[j]+1 .. end[i], then update dp[i] such that you reset the number of ways if choosing j is better. If choosing j will result the same number of used intervals, then you increment the number of ways for interval i.

Comment: It's surely not O( 2 ^ n ) :D N can be as big as **100** and I think 2 ^ 100 is a little too much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your solution idea, but I describe my AC solution:

I'm using function with memorization, but you can re-write it using non-recurcive DP.

Let's say we have our intervals in array

pair a[100];
where 
a[i].first is interval begin and a[i].second is interval end.

Sort this array by *begin* first (default behavior of stl sort algorithm with default pair comparator).

Now imagine that we are 'putting' intervals one by one from beginning to end.

let f(int x, int prev) return the number of ways to finish the filling if currently last interval is x and previous is 'prev'.

we'll calculate it as follows:

```
int f(int x, int prev) {
  // if already calculated dp[x][prev], return it. Otherwise, calculate it
  if (dp[x][prev] != -1) {
    return dp[x][prev];
  }
  if (a[x].second == m) {
    return dp[x][prev] = 1; // it means - X is last interval in day
  }
  else {
    dp[x][prev] = 0;
    for (int i = x + 1; i < n; ++i) { // try to select next interval
      if (a[i].first <= a[x].second && // there must be not empty space after x interval
          a[i].second > a[x].second && // if this is false, the set won't be minimal - i interval is useless
          a[i].first > a[x].first && // if this is false, the set won't be minimal, x interval is useless
          a[prev].second < a[i].first) { // if this is false, the set won't be minimal, x interval is useless.  
        dp[x][prev] = (dp[x][prev] + f(i, x)) % 100000000;
      }
    }
  }
  return dp[x][prev];
}
```

After that we need to call this function for every pair of intervals, first of which start at 0 and second is connected with first:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  if (a[i].first == 0) {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        if (a[j].first > 0 && // we don't need to start at 0 - in this case either i or j will be useless
            a[j].first <= a[i].second && // there must be no space after i interval
            a[j].second > a[i].second) { // in opposite case j will be useless
           res = (res + f(j, i)) % 100000000;
        }
     }
     // also we need to check the case when we use only one interval:
     if (a[i].second == m) {
        res = (res + 1) % 100000000;
     }
  }
}
```

After that we only need to print the res.

Comment: How can it ever count anything? You only consider i values where a[i].first == 0, then you only consider j values where a[j].first > 0 and a[j].first <= a[i].first. Given the first comparison, the second is a contradiction and you will never call f(j, i)

Comment: whoops, made a mistake while formatting the code. Thanks, edited.